# using an array of words to filter words from a second array

Tags: python, filtering

I am comparing two arrays in Python.

The 1st array is a list of words from a query string. The second array is the list of words to be excluded from the query.

I have to compare these arrays and exclude words from the first array which are contained in the second array.

I tried to solve this by comparing each word from the first array to the whole of second array and continuing until all the words from the first array are exhausted:

```
for i in q_str:
    if  q_str[i] in stop_arr:
        continue
    else:
        sans_arr[j] = q_arr[i]
        j = j + 1
```

Where `q_str` is the query array, `stop_arr` contains the words to be excluded, and 
`sans_arr` is a new array with the words excluded.

This code generates an error:

> list indices must be integers not str

Comment: Please provide types of `q_str`, `stop_arr` and `sans_arr`. _Array_ is not one of the types in Python, similar types are: `tuple`, `list`, `dict`.

Comment: @colin: it still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code generates new array with all elements of `q_str` that not exists in `stop_arr`:

```
sans_arr = [ x for x in q_str if x not in stop_arr ]
```

Disclaimer: I don't know if q_str is an array of string because you talk about a query array.

Answer (score 9):

Use sets instead of lists, which gives easy access to set operations, such as subtraction:

```
set1 = set(q_str)
set2 = set(stop_arr)

set3 = set1 - set2  # things which are in set1, but not in set2

# or

set4 = set1.difference(set2) # things which are in set1, but not in set2
```

Here's an example:

```
>>> u = set([1,2,3,4])
>>> v = set([3,4,5,6])
>>> u - v
set([1, 2])
>>> u.difference(v)
set([1, 2])
>>> v.difference(u)
set([5, 6])
```

Comment: Sets are an ideal way to approach this problem.  +1 from me.

Comment: @Makoto: Actually you do not really know what OP wants to achieve, because 1) you do not know the types of variables, 2) the example code may suggest some of the variables are dictionaries, 3) query string should be rather represented as a dictionary, not a list/set.

Comment: @Tadeck, the code suggests a dictionary, but the error suggests a list.

Answer (score 2):

It is not entirely clear whether you wish to preserve the ordering of words in `q_str`. If you do:

```
import re
q_str = 'I am comparing 2 arrays in python. both are character arrays. the 1st array is a list of words from a query string. the second array is the list of words to be excluded from the query.'
q_arr = re.split(r'[\s.,;]+', q_str)
stop_arr = set(['a', 'the', 'of', 'is', 'in', 'to', 'be', 'am', 'are', ''])
print [w for w in q_arr if w not in stop_arr]
```

This produces:

```
['I', 'comparing', '2', 'arrays', 'python', 'both', 'character', 'arrays', '1st',
 'array', 'list', 'words', 'from', 'query', 'string', 'second', 'array', 'list',
 'words', 'excluded', 'from', 'query']
```

Answer (score 0):

'for i in q_str' iterates over the list in your loop returning a string each time.

I would lose the [i] in your loop

```
for word in q_str: 
   if  word in stop_arr: 
      continue 
   else: 
     sans_arr[j] = word
     j=j+1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are iterating over a list with a for loop, you will get the elements of the list, not indices.  This means that `i` will actually be the strings from `q_str`, so instead of doing `if q_str[i] in stop_arr` you can check `if i in stop_arr`.  This also means that you want to add `i` to `sans_arr` instead of `q_arr[i]`.

Also, unless `sans_arr` has already been created with a certain length, you probably want to do `sans_arr.append(i)` instead of your current approach of setting the element at a specific index and then incrementing your current index.

And since `i` makes more sense for an index than a word, I have renamed `i` in the loop to `word`:

```
for word in q_str:
    if word in stop_arr:
        continue
    else:
        sans_arr.append(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution for filtering query string keys-values

I assume `q_str` is the dictionary of key-value pairs from query string, `stop_arr` is a list with keys you do not want, and `sans_arr` is filtered `q_str`, without keys existing in `stop_arr`.

Under the above assumptions, the solution would look like this:

```
sans_arr = {x: q_str[x] for x in q_str if x not in stop_arr}
```

### Test

This is how it works:

```
>>> q_str = {
    'test1': 'val1',
    'test2': 'val2',
    'test3': 'val3'
    }
>>> stop_arr = ['test3','test4']
>>> sans_arr = {x: q_str[x] for x in q_str if x not in stop_arr}
>>> sans_arr
{'test1': 'val1', 'test2': 'val2'}
```